# OAuth error after installing on pythonanywhere

Tags: oauth-2.0, wsgi, bottle, pythonanywhere, fitbit

I developed a Python webapp using [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org) locally and have it (mostly) working on [pythonanywhere](http://pythonanywhere.com).

That said, when I try to authenticate a user (which worked on my local installation), I get the following error:

`Redirect_uri mismatch: null. Visit https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2 for more information on the Fitbit Web API authorization process.`

I have updated my fitbit api application settings and triple-checked that my redirect_uri in the setting matches that in my application.

Taking a look at the fitbit docs forums, it appears that [this could be a percent-encoding issue](https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Web-API-Development/oauth-2-0-callback-url-issue/m-p/2105994#M7944) where...

`https://www.fitbit.com/login?disableThirdPartyLogin=true&redirect=%2Foauth2%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%XXXXXXXX%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fcallback%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dactivity%2Bsleep%2Bweight%2Bnutrition%2Bsettings%26state%3D024`

should be...

`https://www.fitbit.com/login?disableThirdPartyLogin=true&redirect=%2Foauth2%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%XXXXXXXX%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp://example.com/callback%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dactivity%2Bsleep%2Bweight%2Bnutrition%2Bsettings%26state%3D024`

The redirect to the authorization page is being built like this...

```
@app.route('/aas/<study_id>')
def hello(study_id):
    '''This is the primary request page that redirects users to the fitbit api for authorization.'''

    authorization_page = f'https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize' \
                         f'?response_type=code' \
                         f'&client_id={CLIENT_ID}' \
                         f'&redirect_uri={str(REDIRECT_URI)}' \
                         f'&scope={SCOPE}' \
                         f'&state={study_id}'    
    redirect(url=authorization_page)
```

Is there a way that I can prevent this encoding from happening, just to SEE if that's the problem? I assume it's being done by wsgi.

Any other thoughts/ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for looking, folks.

Turns out that I wasn't passing the URI in the Authorization Code Grant Flow (second portion of the oauth handshake) as so...

```
POST https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token
Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50X2lkOmNsaWVudCBzZWNyZXQ=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=22942C&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com/callback%2Ffitbit_auth&code=1234567890
```

I still have no idea why it worked on my local server and not on pythonanywhere, but it's fixed.